# How to correctly show or hide ImageView for items in CardView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview, custom-adapter

I am struggling with this problem for a long time.

I'm using `RecyclerView` with attached `SnapHelper`, and my items are scrolling horizontally. I want to set visibility of `ImageViews` in every `CardView` item according to particular data of that Card. Everything seems to be working fine, but it's actually not.

When app is started, all `CardView` items are normal, `ImageViews` which should be visible are visible, the one that shouldn't are not.

But when I click on `CardView`, new Activity opens. When I return to previous Activity, for no reason at all, `ImageView` which should be GONE is visible. And this happens for random `CardView` items.

This is my card_view_item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/airplane"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Airplane"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/airplaneImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:transitionName="image_transition" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/airplaneCondition"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:transitionName="condition_transition"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/condition" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/airplaneAvailable"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:transitionName="availa

ble_transition"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/available" />



        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    ...
     Airplane arplane = airplaneArray.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    ...


     if (airplane.getCondition() == 1) {
        airpaneCondition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        airpaneCondition.setImageResource(R.drawable.condition);
    } else if (airplane.getVisited() == 0) {
        airpaneCondition.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        airpaneCondition.setImageResource(R.drawable.condition);
    }
    if (airplane.getAvailable() == 1) {
        airplaneAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        airplaneAvailable.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);
    } else if (airplane.getAvailable() == 0) {
        airplaneAvailable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        airplaneAvailable.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can save GONE state with position of your cardview or imageview

Comment: probably listposition isn't restarted onbackpressed

Comment: this is a recycling issues, your must not have a default initial state for imageView. on onBindViewHolder, you have to specify visible/Gone for each imageView, your code logic must be if/else if/ else for default state otherwise the last state will be used...

Comment: I've added **else** for default state - but same thing happens again.

Comment: Where are you setting the adapter? onCreate() or onResume()? Also you can try refreshDatasetChanged() inside onResume(), it might solve the problem

Comment: Thanks! I am setting adapter in **onCreate()** method. I've tried to add _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()_ in **onResume()** method, but there's a weird problem - ImageView which shouldn't be visible is first Visible for a small pariod of time (when I return from another Activity) - and after that it is set to GONE. How can I solve this issue? It's still not working as it should - ImageView is again VISIBLE or GONE for random actions. Why is this thing happening ?!?

Comment: could you please make this, on the onBindViewHolder, make all ImageView visible, after that, refactor your code to make gone to match your requirement. this will work all time...

Answer (score 0):

this is issue is caused by recycler view recycling items.
i think the easiest way will be to make all imageView visible and refactor your code to match your business logic...

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    ...
     Airplane arplane = airplaneArray.get(listPosition);
    ...
 airpaneCondition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 airplaneAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//your business logic code...


}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make all ImageViews VISIBLE (or GONE too) before _if condition_, but same thing happens as before. I don't know what's wrong any more

Comment: so keep this and log your data to see if the data has changed! also, why your are using holder. getAdapterPosition instead of listPosition? i think that you must use listPosition

Comment: If I put _Log.d_ in **onBindViewHolder** to see if the data has changed when user is returned from different Acitivity, but I can see data only once when the app is loaded. I have changed _holder.getAdapterPosition()_ to _listPosition_, but this has absolutely no effect. The problem is still present!

Comment: Practically the problem now is that ImageView which is hidden is shown for a short periond of time when user **clicks** on CardView to start another Activity, and also when user gets back from the previous Activity.

Comment: could you please share hole code for Adapter and Activity... to debug this behaviour you have to log all call to onBindViewHolder and check your data... are you calling data change correctly? is your airplaneArray and Airplane immutable?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a harder way to do this but you could also set up multiple viewholders and have a viewholder that has the image views you want and another that doesnt I forget exactly how to accomplish this but it is something like you put the logic for your conditions in bindview and depending on condition it sets the viewholder. This method worked well for me in a particular case.